# Customer menu is not displaying after login

Tags: magento2.3, frontend, myaccount

We are building our website using Magento 2.3 EE. We have extended the luma theme. While we test our site, we have found out that there is no links for customer to go to My account page. Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

I'm not sure that what I have missed. Can anyone please help me to resolv this issue?

Comment: Try to run deploy and all command one and then check

Comment: I have already done that but still not working

Comment: Have you installed any theme?

Comment: We have extended the luma theme.

Answer (score 2):

Add default.xml in `app/design/frontend/your-theme-namespace/yourtheme/Magento_Sales/layout` with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link-top" after="my-account-link" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">sales/order/history</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Orders</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I hope this will be helpful.